# Event hub throttled requests

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

We use Event Hub messaging services on Azure with Kafka and In the azure portal metrics we have some throttled requests

[image]

I inspect the total of events in the topics and I have exactly the expected number, no message lost.

So what does exactly throttled requests means ? what does it mean to deny requests ? Does the producer or the consumer loose some messages ?

Comment: [How exactly does Event Hubs Throttling Work?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/messaging-on-azure-blog/how-exactly-does-event-hubs-throttling-work/ba-p/370672), [EventHub Throttle and TU relationship](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/11034) and [Scaling with Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-scalability)

Comment: Throttled requests mean denying a request this mainly happens when you have huge traffic which is something around 1000 events per second.

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru-MT What does it mean denying requests ?

Comment: This can also happen if the message size is beyond the allowed tiered limits.

Comment: Regarding # of message matching i think the client(producer) sending the request might end up retrying, but there might be instance the request was throlled and deny'd. Client ended up retrying and succeeding :)